# How connect programmaticaly the UISlider with a Label below of the slider which the view is normaly to all iphone screens?

Tags: ios, swift, label, uislider

I make an array for the range of a UISlider, and I put each values on a label below the slider, but if I change iPhone screen (5s, 6s, 8, Xr)
the label doesn't show the correct position of the UISlider values.

How should I connect the range of UISlider array values, with the Label below for every iPhone screen?

[Expected results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1hial.png)

[Debug View Hierarchy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uCIer.png)

There is a method for the setup Auto Layout regardless of the different iphone screen . Where you see Easy.Layout that is EasyPeasy Auto-Layout is the same of Apple documentation Auto Layout Constrains.

```
func setupLabels() {
    let values = [0, 3.7, 11, 22, 43, 50, 100]
    values.forEach({
        let sliderValuesLabel = UILabel()
        if $0 == values.first {
            sliderValuesLabel.text = "ALLE"
            wrapperView.addSubview(sliderValuesLabel)
            sliderValuesLabel.easy.layout(

                Top(15).to(uislider),
                Leading().to(uislider, .leading), // Left Position
                Bottom(1)
            )

        } else if $0 == values.last {
            sliderValuesLabel.text = "\(Int($0))+"
            wrapperView.addSubview(sliderValuesLabel)
            sliderValuesLabel.easy.layout(
                Trailing().to(uislider, .trailing), // Right Position
                Top(15).to(uislider),
                Bottom(1)
            )

        } else  {
            sliderValuesLabel.text = "\(Int($0))"
            wrapperView.addSubview(sliderValuesLabel)

            let thumbRect = uislider.thumbRect(forBounds: uislider.bounds,
                                               trackRect: uislider.trackRect(forBounds: uislider.bounds),
                                               value: uislider.value)
            let thumRectToView = uislider.convert(thumbRect, to: uislider ) // Convert

            sliderValuesLabel.easy.layout(
                Top(15).to(uislider),
                Bottom(1),
                CenterX(thumRectToView.midX)

            )
        }
    })

}
```

Comment: The problem is that you're giving the label a fixed size that will be the same across any screen. If you want it to be responsive you'll have to use AutoLayout (use the multiplier in the equation), and you'll need several labels, not just one.

Comment: i will try it , Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

You will need to set constraints on the label using Auto-Layout. This will keep it in a fixed position on all devices.

Comment: What about the return value of slider.value ..?? Look on the image, above of thumb there is a label above with 11km string  and 11 label below of thumb i want the same value to all iphone screens

Comment: @PMour Does that slide along with the thumb?

Comment: I want to take dynamically the trackRect position and assign that value in above slider labels with the constrains